# Fix Subversion Ancestry

Tags: svn

I have a collection of projects which all derive from a common framework.  This framework provides some files that are relatively static (the same across all projects), some files that each user must modify parts of (similar across projects), and a few files that the user must provide (present but unrelated across projects).

Looking through the history of commits I see commits to these common files have been done in a sort of cross cutting fashion.  For instance in one commit I see the same file updated in the same way across all of the projects.  There is no original branching that establishes an ancestry relation between these files, instead the original developers just checked in the original files and all subsequent changes independently.

Is there some correct way to fix this in Subversion?  Is there some way I can make commits now to establish new ancestry?  I really don't care about correcting all the wrongness already done, I just need a way to coerce the repository into properly handling merges going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no graceful way to recover from this.  The fundamental limitation is that SVN apparently cannot manage multiple ancestry.  It assumes a file has exactly one parent.  Because of this you can not take an existing file and merge in an unrelated branch expecting future merges from that unrelated branch to merge cleanly.

In the end my resolution was:

1. Checkout two copies of the project in question, a working copy and a backup.
2. Delete any files which should have been branched from the common framework originally.  Leave these deletes in your working copy (i.e. don't commit yet)
3. SVN copy the common framework's files into your working copy.  These files should have the same names as the previously deleted files, and their SVN status should now say "Replaced" or 'R'.  You should do this copy from whatever version of the framework's files the original project should have branched from.
4. Copy (just a regular file system copy) the files from your backup over top of your working copy.  This restores the content of the files so that the only actual change is to the ancestry.
5. run a diff to make sure you didn't overlook something
6. Commit.

At this point you have files with identical content, but their ancestry indicates they came from the framework files.  If you have new versions of the framework you should now be able to easily do a merge from the framework into your project.

Comment: You cured the symptoms, but not the disease.  You'll be doing this again, probably sooner than you think.  Since the source code is copied, you have multiple copies which must be in sync.  That's less likely to happen over time than one copy which is reused by others.

Comment: Yes, well, I can't avoid that problem since it's fundamental to the architecture all these projects are built on (files have to have specific names, have to be all in one directory, have to have certain magic sections, etc) in order to make the fairly antiquated build system happy.  In the end there will always be file level sharing (it's an embedded system's roll-your-own OS).  I'm just trying to get the ground truth reflected properly in the version control system.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the class out into it's own subversion repository.

1. Create a new SVN repo.
2. Identify the best version of the copied classes.
3. Add those components to the new repository.
4. Add a pom.xml file to build a jar of common components.
5. Commit everything, and then check out to the "build server"
6. Build the release version of the common components.
7. Go through repositories one-by-one, removing the offending classes, and reworking the build to use the common components.

For best results, do not make the projects dependent on a "SNAPSHOT" version, have a real release version, and bump the projects up when they need the latest release version.

Other solutions exist; however, they tend to be temporary solutions.  For example, the "how to sync files between projects" plan offered by Speed8ump does work (and works well), until someone once again modifies one of the copies without distributing their changes across all the other duplicates.

Comment: Yep, that's the state of affairs here.  Projects start from the "latest core components" get developed deployed and sustained.  Then if there's some specific reason (usually a bugfix or new feature) the trunk gets dragged kicking and screaming to the latest core files.  Your suggestion is right, except it can't be easily done for structural reasons.  Maybe in another few years I'll have dragged us into the 21st century far enough for actual common libraries rather than common sources.